# How to run a function against an array of inputs?

Tags: python, numpy

How can I use numpy to generate an array of models by calling a function `f()`?

Say for example I have a list of values I want to use: `z = [0,0.1,0.25]`

Can run a function :  `f(x,y,z_i)` where `z_i` is a variable in `z`?

I was thinking I can use something like `arr = np.array(map(f(x,y,z),z)` but I'm not sure how to relate the function inputs with the array I want to use.

Comment: Do you mean `np.array(map(lambda z_i: f(x, y, z_i), z))` or `np.array(map(functools.partial(f, x, y), z))`?

Comment: Is it not possible to generate that array inside the function itself based on the length of z, and then return that array back from the function? or is a **one-liner required**?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What are the shapes of `x` and `y`?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the expresiveness of a list comprehension

```
 np.array([f(x,y,zi) for zi in z])
```